# Topological insulators: What does the scattering matrix at an topological edge tell about the Chern number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, boundary-conditions, topological-insulators

In class we were briefly discussing, that one way to see if the edge of a TI carries a state is to consider the scattering of a lead that is attached to this edge. In fact the argument was more general: consider the surface of a solid with a lead attached, that is cut off at some point. A state living on the surfaces running into the lead is connected to a state coming from the lead via the reflection matrix.
$$\Psi_{in} = R(\theta) \Psi_{out}$$
If there is a state living on the surface then scattering on the end of the lead means acquiring a phase of -1 (the end is a hard wall). Therefore
$$\Psi_{in} = - \Psi_{out}$$
combining the statements a condition that a (topological) state lives on the surface (edge) is then
$$det(R(\theta)+1) = 0$$
Now the argument continued that the scattering matrix can be viewed as a phase $e^{i\theta}$. Here $\theta$ is depending on the momentum along the surfaces, so that $\theta = \theta(k)$. Continuity now demands that $$\theta(k+2\pi) = \theta(k)+n \cdot 2\pi$$
The main point now is that if $n \neq 0$ the phase winds at least once while moving through the Brillouin zone and that guarantees that there is a state at the given energy living on the surface. Can someone explain to me why a phase winding looking like the figure below does exclude any state from the surface?

[image: figure 1][image: figure 2]

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.165409 this might be of interest.